# jQuery load event (maybe) not passing variables properly

Tags: php, jquery, load

I have the below code, which is basically supposed to take the `<div class="mainSection">` tag and empty the contents.
It then runs the `.load` event to repopulate it using the contents of `displayData.php`
It passes across two variables, `custID` and `custName`, and in my test script (below) simply writes them back to the screen to verify it has worked.

I am obviously missing something, and can't for the life of me see what.
Everything appears to be OK, except that the variables never seem to make it into `displayData.php` which always reports back `NA - NA`.

I must be missing something, (probably really obvious). . .

```
custID = 123;
custName = 'TestName';

$.when($('.mainSection').fadeOut('slow')).done(function()
    {
        alert(custID + custName); //confirms that variables are set and hold the data expected
        $('.mainSection')
            .empty()
            .load('displayData.php',
                {
                    'custID':custID, 
                    'custName':custName
                },function(responseTxt,statusTxt,xhr)
                    {
                        if(statusTxt=="success")
                        alert("External content loaded successfully!");

                        if(statusTxt=="error")
                        alert("Error: "+xhr.status+": "+xhr.statusText);
                    }
                )
            .fadeIn();  
    })

---
displayData.php 

<?php

$custID = (ISSET($_GET['custID']) ? $_GET['custID'] : 'NA');
$custName = (ISSET($_GET['custName']) ? $_GET['custName'] : 'NA');


print $custID." - ".$custName;

?>
```

Comment: You are mixing JS and PHP variables. Try `.load('display.php?custID=' + custID + '&custName=' + custName)`

Comment: are you sure that .load() is called properly? And there is only one mainSection ?

Comment: It's one of those days!! It's so obvious once someone points it out. Cheers Marcell, that fixed it.

Comment: What version of jquery are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to

1) wrap it in a document ready function for load to work

2) update load to pass in the parameters via get in the url

***fadeIn doesn't work properly if you have alerts.**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){  

custID = 123;
custName = 'TestName';

$.when($('.mainSection').fadeOut('slow')).done(function()
{        
    $('.mainSection')
        .empty()
        .fadeIn('slow')
        .load('display.php?custID=' + custID + '&custName=' + custName,  
         function(responseTxt,statusTxt,xhr) {

              if(statusTxt=="success")
                  alert("External content loaded successfully!");

              if(statusTxt=="error")
                  alert("Error: "+xhr.status+": "+xhr.statusText);
          });  
});

});
```